# How to merge two dataframes in pyspark with different columns inside struct or array?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

Lets say, there are two data-frames. **Reference dataframe** and **Target dataframe**.

Reference DF is a reference schema.

**Schema for reference DF (r_df)**

> ```
> r_df.printSchema()
> ```

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- notificationsSend: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- mail: boolean (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sms: boolean (nullable = true)
 |-- recordingDetails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- channelName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fileLink: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- recorderId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- resourceId: string (nullable = true)
```

However, target data-frame schema is dynamic in nature.

**Schema for target DF (t_df)**

> t_df.printSchema()

```
root
 |-- _id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- notificationsSend: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sms: string (nullable = true)
 |-- recordingDetails: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- channelName: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- fileLink: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- recorderId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- resourceId: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- createdBy: string (nullable = true)
```

So we observe multiple changes in target's schema.

1. Columns inside **t_df** struct or array can have more or less columns.
2. Datatype of columns can change too. So type casting is required. (Ex. **sms** column is **boolean** in **r_df** but **string** in **t_df**)

I was able to add/remove columns which are of non-struct datatype. However, struct and arrays are real pain for me. Since there are 50+ columns, I need an optimised solution which works for all.

Any solution/ opinion/ way around will be really helpful.

**Expected output**
I want to make my **t_df**'s schema exactly same as my **r_df**'s schema.

Comment: What exactly you are looking for? You need to cast those nested columns? You want to join these two dfs? It's not exactly clear

Comment: Apologies for not clarifying expected output. I have edited the question now. Basically I need my target df's schema to be same as my reference df's schema.

Comment: What version of spark are you on ? Is it a requirement to maintain the struct or can you flatten it to a table?(without the structs)

Comment: in your exemple you have ```mail``` in ```r_df```and not in ```t_df```. You want to create this column in ```t_df``` for this case? And for  ```createdBy```? Do you want to drop from ```t_df``` or create it in ```r_df```?

Comment: @LuizViola Yes, r_df is my empty reference data-frame just to read the schema. Based on r_df I have to either create or drop columns in t_df. Or cast w.r.t. r_df columns

Answer (score 0):

*below code is un-tested* but should prescribe how to do it. (written from memory without testing.)
There may be a way to get fields from a struct but I'm not aware how so i'm interested to hear others ideas.

1. Extract struct [column names and types.](https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-find-datatype-column-names-of-dataframe/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20find%20all%20column,schema%5B%22name%22%5D.)
2. Find columns that need to be dropped
3. Drop columns
4. rebuild struts according to r_df.

```
stucts_in_r_df = [  field.name for field in r_df.schema.fields if(str(field.dataType).startswith("Struct")) ] # use list comprehension to create a list of struct fields

struct_columns = []
for structs in stucts_in_r_df: # get a list of fields in the structs
 struct_columns.append(r_df\
  .select(
   "$structs.*"
  ).columns
 )

missingColumns = list(set(r_df.columns) - set(tdf.columns)) # find missing columns
similiar_Columns = list(set(r_df.columns).intersect(set(tdf.columns))))
#remove struct columns from both lists so you don't represent them twice.

# you need to repeat the above intersection/missing for the structs and then rebuild them but really the above gives you the idea of how to get the fields out.
# you can use variable replacemens  col("$struct.$field") to get the values out of the fields,
result = r_df.union(
 tdf\ 
  .select(*(
   [ lit(None).cast(dict(r_df.dtypes)[column]).alias(column) for column in missingColumns] +\
   [ col(column).cast(dict(r_df.dtypes)[column]).alias(column) for column in similiar_Columns] ) # using list comprehension with joins and then passing as varargs to select will completely dynamically pull out the values you need.
  )
 )
```

Here's a way once you have the union to pull back the struct:

```
result = result\
 .select(
   col("_id"),
   struct( col("sms").alias("sms") ).alias("notificationsSend"),
   struct( *[col(column).alias(column) for column in struct_columns] # pass varags to struct with columns
    ).alias("recordingDetails") #reconstitue struct with 
  )
```

Comment: added reconstitution of struct

Comment: Appreciated the efforts. However, there are some limitations. I can't call columns explicitly as I don't know what columns I'll be receiving in t_df. So I use r_df to refer all columns. If t_df has columns similar to r_df's, I keep it. If not, I have to drop it. Also if there is mismatch in datatype of single column, I have to cast by what datatype r_df's column has.

Comment: Yup no problem. What I have presented to you can be modified to do that. Tomorrow I can make the changes. Please update your problem statement to reflect this information.